# Spring Boot - Loading 'logback.xml' from the WEB-INF/ folder when deploying as WAR

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, logback

I'm working on updating a traditional Spring MVC application to Spring Boot (deployed as WAR).

One requirement is that in order to retain compatibility with our remote installations, the `logback.xml` file *needs* to be in the following location in the deployed webapp:

`webapp/WEB-INF/logback.xml`

In the project source, if I put the file in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/logback.xml`, it gets successfully copied to `webapp/WEB-INF/logback.xml`, but I can' find a way to load it and use it from that location.

I've tried setting the Spring Boot `logging.config` property to the following:

```
logging.config=/WEB-INF/logback.xml
```

hoping that the auto-configuration would take care of it, but this fails without an error message and the default Spring Boot logging configuration gets loaded instead.

What is the proper way of handling this with Spring Boot? (example code is welcome)

Comment: I think the problem is not related to Spring Boot but the fact that `/WEB-INF` is not on the classpath, only `/WEB-INF/classes`. Logback tries to find the xml on the classpath. If you cannot move the file to `classes`, you need to figure out how to add /WEB-INF to the classpath. Not sure there is an easy and application server independent way to do that. Google `war custom classpath` and you'll see.

Comment: I think the problem is not related to Spring Boot but the fact that `/WEB-INF` is not on the classpath, only `/WEB-INF/classes`. Logback tries to find the xml on the classpath. If you cannot move the file to `classes`, you need to figure out how to add /WEB-INF to the classpath. Not sure there is an easy and application server independent way to do that. Google `war custom classpath` and you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be needing a hack:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    // In case of regular deployments, use WEB-INF/logback.xml
    @Override 
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        configureLogging(servletContext);
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).info("Done configuring");
    }

    // manually configure logging
    private void configureLogging(final ServletContext servletContext) {
        try {
            String realPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/logback.xml");
            LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
            JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
            configurator.setContext(context);
            context.reset();
            configurator.doConfigure(realPath);
        } catch (JoranException je) {
            // StatusPrinter will handle this
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Also, I had **logback-spring.xml** in `src/main/resources`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="logback-include.xml" />
</configuration>
```

And **logback-include.xml** in `src/main/resources`, which had some common configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<included>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />

    <!-- put your loggers here -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.web" additivity="false" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- put your root here -->
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</included>
```

And, finally, logback.xml in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` that imported the common config just like logback-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="logback-include.xml" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: This results in the following WARN message: `|-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.IncludeAction - Could not find resource corresponding to [/WEB-INF/logback.xml]`

Comment: As for the second part - the way I understand the quoted documentation is that only using the `@PropertySources` annotation won't work - the "conventional" external configuration (f.i. setting the properties via application.properties, like I'm trying) should work according to the quote. I might be misunderstanding though. :)

Comment: Hmmm, I think you are right, I just tried it. And I also think that Arthur's comment on your question is also right - in my answer I did not try deploying the artifact, I just ran it through mvn spring-boot:run and it worked fine there; however, it did not work when deployed. I'll update my answer with the solution

Comment: A bit ugly, but hey - if you can't autowire them, join them! :) I ended up implementing a somewhat simpler version with just a single `logback.xml` in the `WEB-INF` folder and all the configuration happening inside a `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` instead of the `onStartup` method.

Comment: its no called in a war deployed external tomcat

Answer (score 2):

Putting `logback.xml` in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` results in the file being copied to `webapp/WEB-INF/`, which is a directory level above `webapp/WEB-INF/classes/` that is on the classpath. Try putting this in your `application.properties`:

```
logging.config=classpath:../logback.xml
```

This way `logback.xml` will be located correctly during initialization. Have a look at [Common Application Properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) for example uses of `classpath:`, which is used to represent the location of the classpath in `application.properties`.

Although, to be honest, I would rather make `logback.xml`, in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`, a symbolic link to `classes/logback.xml` (which would make sense for deployment (and would be useful in your remote installations), since `webapp/WEB-INF/logback.xml` will then link to `webapp/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml`) and keep my spring-boot application more conventional, by putting `logback.xml` in `src/main/resources` (which would be copied in `webapp/WEB-INF/classes/`). Since I do not know the specifics of your remote installations and what you mean by compatibility, this may or may not work.

Comment: Setting `logging.config=classpath:../logback.xml` silently fails as well. The symlink suggestion is interesting, but likely inapplicable in our case.

Comment: @vtosh What do you mean by "silently"? Like `logging.config=/WEB-INF/logback.xml` fails for you, that is with the default logging configuration being loaded?